# Receive array of objects asp net API

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core

I have an angular app thats sends an array of objects and a .NET API server.

The problem is that my .NET does receive the data but it cannot bind it to objects correctly.

Angular Frontend App:

```
data: IAccountBookKeeping[] = [];

onClickSendToAPI(){

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

 const stringify = fastJson({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    AccountingDate: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    RegistrationNo: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    Currency: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    IDKT: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    OriginalIDKT: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    CounterAccountIDKT: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    ProjectCode: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    Balance: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    Text: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
})


const jsonString: string[] = [];

this.data.forEach(element => {
  jsonString.push(stringify(this.data[0]));
});

this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/GFSAccount',
JSON.stringify(jsonString),
 httpOptions).subscribe(reponse =>
console.log(reponse));
```

}

What Angular Frontend send to the API

[" 
{\"AccountingDate\":\"20171130\",\"RegistrationNo\":\"39A1\",\"Currency\":\"DKK\",\"IDKT\":\"34HS991016\",\"OriginalIDKT\":\"test\",\"CounterAccountIDKT\":\"34HS980876\",\"ProjectCode\":\"078\",\"Balance\":\"1\",\"Text\":\"006-Hest prov-Ytd NOV17\"}","{\"AccountingDate\":\"20171130\",\"RegistrationNo\":\"39A1\",\"Currency\":\"DKK\",\"IDKT\":\"34HS991016\",\"OriginalIDKT\":\"test\",\"CounterAccountIDKT\":\"34HS980876\",\"ProjectCode\":\"078\",\"Balance\":\"1\",\"Text\":\"006-Hest prov-Ytd NOV17\"}"

ASP .NET API Server Receiving

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<AccountBookKeeping> request)
    {
      return Ok(request);
    }
```

ASP .NET AccountBookKeeping Class

```
public class AccountBookKeeping
{
    public string AccountingDate { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
    public string IDKT { get; set; }
    public string OriginalIDKT { get; set; }
    public string CounterAccountIDKT { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.data`? The array you want to post?

Comment: Yes, it's the array I would like to send: data: IAccountBookKeeping[] = [];

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post an array as the body of a `post`, then just pass the array in directly. There's no need to heavily process it through `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/GFSAccount';
this.http.post(url, this.data, httpOptions).subscribe(reponse =>
  console.log(reponse);
});
```

As an aside, your existing loop is just building an array with the first element repeated:

```
this.data.forEach(element => {
  jsonString.push(stringify(this.data[0]));
});
```

But this step is irrelevant if you just pass the array in as the body.

Comment: I tried this. ASP. NET will give back a Null. I will also get a status code 307 temporary redirect.

Comment: What about `public IActionResult Post(AccountBookKeeping[] request)`?

Comment: This will give 201 Ok but send back an empty array

Comment: Why a 201? Your code is returning `Ok` which should be a 200. When I run ```this.http.post(`${apiUrl}/test`, [1, 2, 3])``` my C# (Framework) controller receives the data: `public IHttpActionResult Test(int[] data)`

Comment: I've meant 200.

Comment: What version of C# web api? Core 2 / 3? Framework 4.x?

Comment: So Core 3. I've just tried this with my core 3 API, and I get the values automatically: ```public IActionResult Test(int[] request)```

Comment: Silly question - have you tried `console.log(this.data)` directly before the request goes out? There's nothing in your example to demonstrate that it's getting updated.

Comment: Yes. Data is in the array before request goes out. No question is silly. Thanks for keep trying to help. :)

Comment: Have you inspected the request itself in the network tab of your browser dev tools?